# Using Spree Commerce without users

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I need to set a website that offers buying based on the session and that's it.

No users, no authentication. You buy with the cart you built in the session.

I haven't actually tried anything.

Please give me an idea of what I can try.

I'm running

- RoR 4.0.0
- Spree 2.1.2

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. Have you found an answer?

Comment: Same here. Did you solved your problem?

Comment: @aelesbao I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree doesn't technically require a user account; the default behavior is to allow creating an account or checking out as a guest (just specifying an email address).

How important is it to not have accounts? In general, people like having an account that they can use to access their order history, etc.

If you truly don't want this functionality, the easiest approach would be to simply hide the login form (using deface) and remove the route.